# How to link same sequence generator to two tables in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables called student and student history. The id of student is generated using a generator. When I insert into student I want the same record to get inserted into history table with the same id. How can I achieve this?

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: You want to copy all the data on-to another history table right?Why do you want to use the same sequence?

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping you define the relation between student and student history as an 1:1 or 1:n relation, and you define cascade for insert/update. For the foreign key to student in the student history table you use a `<key>` element (to be defined in the mapping for student).

For example (here a 1:n relation) you do in the mapping of **student**:

```
<bag name="studentHistory" cascade="all" ... >
  <key column="studentId" not-null="true">
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.xxx.StudentHistory"/>
</bag>
```

Then when you update/insert the student instance, the foreign key in the history is handled automatically by hibernate.